# Is there a way to convert a non zero padded time string into a datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

I am looking a the [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) docs. It only specifies that it can read formatted times with zero padded strings like '01:00pm'. Is there a way I can read a time like '1:00am' using the strptime function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same format string to read a time like "1:00 AM" that isn't padded with zeroes. This is mentioned in note (9) of the [technical details section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail):

> When used with the strptime() method, the leading zero is optional for formats %d, %m, %H, %I, %M, %S, %j, %U, %W, and %V. Format %y does require a leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably pad the time using regular string functions assuming you only want to pad the hours.

```py
time_string = '1:00am'

# Splits the string where ':' is
time_string_split = time_string.split(':')

# Uses a ternary operator to check the hour digits then pads accordingly
time_string_split[0] = '0' + time_string_split[0] if len(time_string_split[0]) < 2 else time_string_split[0]

# Joins it together again with a ':'
time_string = ':'.join(time_string_split)

print(time_string) # '01:00am'
```

Or a simpler approach

```py
time_string = '1:00am'

time_string_split = time_string.split(':')

if len(time_string_split[0]) < 2: 
    time_string_split[0] = '0' + time_string_split[0]

time_string = ':'.join(time_string_split)

print(time_string) # '01:00am'
```

Hope this helps!